# Como gerar barra de carregamento Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Eu preciso mostrar para meu usuário durante uma requisição Ajax os status da mesma dividido em 6 etapas Ex.

> ```
> 1° : Gerando arquiv
> 2° : Arquivo Gerado
> 3°: Conectando FTP
> 4º: Conexão realizada
> 5º:  Enviando arquivo 
> 6º : Arquivo enviado
> ```

Comment: Ok. Qual é o problema?

Comment: Atualmente  consigo implementar isto renderizando apenas o response  final da requisição. Já agora preciso que o usuário veja em tela varias etapas do processo até o fim.

Comment: Aqui está a documentação oficial, divide 100% pelo números de steps que vc precisa e altera os valores na hora de cada requisição https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo que acho que está mais próximo do que vc precisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301397/how-can-i-make-a-series-of-steps-for-a-progress-bar-in-a-multi-step-form

Comment: Penso que o problema está no lado servidor

Comment: Isto mesmo @JorgeCosta , como devo proceder no Back-end?, feito isto como tratar este retorno com o Jquery em tempo de execução mostrando para o usuário cada etapa do processo ? estou conseguindo ser claro ?

Comment: Que tipo de tecnologia está a usar do lado do servidor

Comment: Servidor Apache ,  framework Laravel

Comment: pelo q li, vc precisa para cada passo descrito, uma função ajax q execute o q vc quer(ou seja, va la no controller, acesse o banco por exemplo e retorna dados pra atualizar sua pagina, informando ao usuario o q foi feito e o q ja está disponivel). 1º gerando Arquivo (crie uma função ajax q executa o q precisa e altere o status do prox passo (2º arquivo gerado). assim por diante).

Comment: Dê uma lida nisso: https://www.binarytides.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/

Answer (score 1):

**Prova de Conceito**

É apenas um exemplo de como poderia ser implementado (não é para usado em produção)

Nota: Lavarel 5.6 utilizando Queues

**Rotas**

```
//dar início a processamento
Route::get('/processar', 'ProcessarArquivoController@processar');

//obter percentagem de acabamento

Route::get('/estadoprocesso/{processo}', 'ProcessarArquivoController@estado');
```

**Controlador**

Tem apenas dois métodos um para dar início ao processo o segundo para verificado o estado do processo (percentagem)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Processo;
use App\Jobs\ProcessarArquivo;

class ProcessarArquivoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Inicia um processo enviando Processo para uma Queue
     * Devolve o modelo do processo em JSON
     * @return JSON
     */
    public function processar()
    {
        $processo = new Processo();
        $processo->percentagem = 5;
        $processo->save();
        ProcessarArquivo::dispatch($processo);
        return response()->json($processo, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Devolve o modelo do processo em JSON
     * @return JSON
     */

    public function estado(Processo $processo)
    {
        return response()->json($processo, 200);
    }
}
```

**Job**

O processo a ser executado pela Queue, não faz nada o sleep é só para não executar de forma instantânea, no caso poderia ser conversão de ficheiro, upload por ftp, etc..

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Processo;

class ProcessarArquivo implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $processo;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Processo $processo)
    {
        $this->processo = $processo;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(2);//executar algo
        $this->processo->percentagem = 20;
        $this->processo->save();
        sleep(2);//executar algo
        $this->processo->percentagem = 30;
        $this->processo->save();
        sleep(2);//executar algo
        $this->processo->percentagem = 40;
        $this->processo->save();
        sleep(2);//executar algo
        $this->processo->percentagem = 50;
        $this->processo->save();
        sleep(2);//executar algo
        $this->processo->arquivo_enviado = 100;
        $this->processo->save();

    }
}
```

**Migration**

Tabela de controlo de execução de processos, apenas um exemplo

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Processo extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('processos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('percentagem')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Página de Front-End**
Bootstrap + jQuery
Apenas um exemplo.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>POC</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p>Progresso</p>

        <div class="card">


            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Processamento</h4>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0"
                                id="progresso" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <a name="" id="processar" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Processar ficheiro</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#processar').click(function () {
                console.log('A iniciar processo...');
                $.getJSON('/processararquivo', function (data) {
                    var id = data.id;
                    window.progresso = setInterval(function () {
                        obterEstado(id)
                    }, 1000)
                });
            });
        });

        function obterEstado(id) {

            $.getJSON('/estadoarquivo/' + id, function (data) {
                console.log('A verificar processo: ' + data.id);
                $("#progresso").css('width', data.percentagem + '%');
                if (data.percentagem == 100) {
                    console.log('A finalizar processo: ' + data.id);
                    clearInterval(window.progresso);
                }
            })
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```